# Serve images and js from different locations ExpressJs: Node

Tags: node.js, express, static-content

I am using the below code to serve statics files(js, images, css):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

But now the images have been moved to some different location in the project i.e. outside the `public` directory (lets say. `images`).

So how do I differentiate between images and js,css files and serve them from different locations?

**EDIT**

I guess I have to read the request headers and then decide where to route the request. But looks a little dirty to me.

Answer (score 5):

Try with two separate endpoints:

```
import express from "express";
import {join} from 'path';

    const app = express();    


    const publicPath = express.static(join(__dirname, '../public/'));
    const publicImages = express.static(join(__dirname, '../images/'));

    app.use('/public', publicPath);
    app.use('/images', publicImages);


    app.listen(3400, function() {
      console.log("Express server listening on port 3400");  
    });
```

Then you use it like this: `http://localhost:3400/images/` and `http://localhost:3400/public/`

Answer (score 0):

In that case you just need to add one more static file configuration

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
```

And it will be served as

> http://example.com/files-from-images-folder

Comment: Tried, but now my js and css files not be served. Also the link doesn't look right

Comment: is this images folder inside "public" folder?

Comment: If you use app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images'))); you may add your file in /yourproject/images/* :)